# Why is facebook not correctly pulling my OG:image?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I am currently having issues with like buttons on a site I am a developer on. I was hoping someone here could help, or at least would like to know if anyone else is experiencing this problem.

So, on this page here: http://www.dailylook.com/c/10-201115-Khaki-White/1/139.html , there are a couple like buttons implemented. Now, I have also run this through the URL debugger, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailylook.com%2Fc%2F10-201115-Khaki-White%2F1%2F139.html , and it is properly bringing back all of my opengraph info.

However, when I actually use the like button, it does not show the image in either the fly-out box that appears in relation to the clicked like button, or the resultant timeline post. Also, I notice that the URL showing below the title in the fly-out is "http://www.facebook.com/pages/DailyL...", which is most certainly not the URL for the page that is being passed to the FB like button. However, in the resultant timeline post, the link is correct.

It seems like everything is set up correctly to me, and the URL debugger seems to agree, so I am trying to figure out if anyone can see something that I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The og:url tag on your page http://www.dailylook.com/c/10-201114-Sexy-OTK-Sequins/1/139.html is pointing to http://www.DailyLook.com/c/10-201115-Khaki-White/1/139.html so the scraper pulls the data from http://www.DailyLook.com/c/10-201115-Khaki-White/1/139.html

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that, the url I should have pasted for review should be http://www.dailylook.com/c/10-201115-Khaki-White/1/139.html , I will change it now. But that actually doesn't really address the issue. They are the same page, technically, because of the 139.html at the end.